# Oracle jpa cannot insert null

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I have the below user entity, the profile of user is optional, when i save the user without the profile i get this error

> ORA-01400: Cannot insert null into ("USER_ENTITY"."PROFILE_FK")

```
@Entity
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "user-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "user-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String userId;

    private String email;

    @OneToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_fk", nullable = true, unique = true)
    private ProfileEntity profile;

}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ProfileEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "profile-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "profile-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String profileId;

    private String email;

}
```

Comment: Looks like the table might have `NOT NULL` for that column, maybe from an earlier iteration of your code. Try dropping and re-creating the tables, so see if that fixes the column definition.

Comment: You don't need to drop anything. ALTER TABLE USER_ENTITY MODIFY <your field> <field type> NULL;